# How to keep CollectionView cells on return to view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView that have cells corresponding to children in Firebase database. My problem is that when I segue to another view, then segue back, the CollectionView cells are gone.

I have a cellForItemAt function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "playerItem", for: indexPath) as! PlayerCollectionViewCell
    cell.setupViews(parentSize: Int(self.playerCollectionView.frame.width), hostUID: self.currentUID, tempUserName: playerArrayList[indexPath.item])
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
    return cell
}
```

I also have another code snippit:

```
for i in 0..<playerArrayList.count{
    print(playerCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))
    //playerCollectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)])
    let cell = playerCollectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)) as! PlayerCollectionViewCell
    cell.tempUserName = playerArrayList[i]
    cell.setupViews(parentSize: Int(self.playerCollectionView.frame.width), hostUID: self.currentUID, tempUserName: playerArrayList[i])
}
```

I still learning how the CollectionView creates cells, and what the program does when a View is asleep, but I believe my problem is that the cellForItemAt function creates all of the cells the first time the view is created and doesn't happen again after.
I am sure of this because when the view is created for the first time, there are three cells(which are exactly how many children there are in the database) however when segued back to the same view, there are no cells.
I have tried to fix this by deleting all the cells then remaking them.
In the code snippet, you can see the commented line:

```
playerCollectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)])
```

however this gives me the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I have also tried using this to create cells:

```
let cell = playerCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "playerItem", for: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)) as! PlayerCollectionViewCell
```

But I get the same error. How can I recreate the cells on return to the View?

Comment: How are you segueing back?  Are you sure you aren't moving forward to a new instance of your original view controller?

Comment: @Paulw11 The two views I am switching between are in the same stack so I am pretty sure it is not a new instance. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5SQeKTVAsVbSEFweEw0dURVejQ/view?usp=sharing The segues themselves are from view controller to view controller and not button to view controller, since I need to perform an operation before segueing.

Comment: If you aren't using the "back" button in your navigation controller then you must make sure you use an unwind segue, otherwise you are continually pushing new instances of your view controllers. Put a log statement or breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` if it gets called more than once then you are creating a new instance.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am using the back button, and I used the print statement to determine that viewDidLoad is being called more than once. How can I either resume the first instance or terminate the current instance on the back button? I am using a show segue from the main menu view to the current view, instead of a button segue. Do i need to change the kind of segue? And if so what kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are implementing methods `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` and `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` in your `UICollectionViewDataSource` object.

When accessing cell with `cellForItem` you should check if you actually get a cell. That method only returns visible cells.

```
if let cell = self.playerCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PlayerCollectionViewCell {
    cell.tempUserName = playerArrayList[i]
    cell.setupViews(parentSize: Int(self.playerCollectionView.frame.width), hostUID: self.currentUID, tempUserName: playerArrayList[i])
}
```

Instead of inserting cells again, you should have a delegate for collection view that tells how many items there are to show

```
override function viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playerCollectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return playerArrayList.count
}
```

`insertItemsAt` method requires that you update return value from `numberOfItemsInSection` to match the new number of items.

If `playerArrayList` object needs reloading you can do that life cycle method

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // reload
}
```

Comment: I have added the if statement to check if i am receiving a cell, and I have added a reload to viewWillAppear. I already had the numberOfItemsInSection function, but i didn't mention it since I didn't believe it was the problem. The good news is that i am receiving no error, however there are now double the cells. The array playerArrayList only has 3 items, but there are 6 cells in the Collection View. What could be the problem? @Mika

Comment: OK, we are half way there then :) I am not able to tell from the code presented here what could be the problem. Maybe review code in cell.setupViews method and check that it clears any views or such that the previous call to that method might have added. Also searching answers for duplicate collection view cells might provide typical situations when cells get duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

you want to reload collection view in viewWillAppear method